# How to join two tables by laravel eloquent model

Tags: php, eloquent

I have two tables one is csps and other one transaction and it has laravel model. I want to join them by laravel eloquent model. I dont wanna use `DB::csps` like this.

**csps Table**

```
'ko_id', 
'ko_name', 
'account_number'
```

**transactions Table**

```
'transaction_date_time', 
'limit_conf_by', 
'ko_id', 
'opening_limit', 
'amount', 
'closing_limit', 
'is_cheque_issued', 
'lot_id', 
'lot_amount',
'deposite_account',
'lot_date',
```

I want to display transaction details with csps detail. I know how to join in database but I want to display by laravel eloquent model. I dont know how join model.

I have tried

**this is Transaction model**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Transaction extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'transactions';
    public $timestamps = false;

    // protected $attributes = [
    //     'delayed' => false,
    // ];

    protected $fillable = [
        'transaction_date_time', 'limit_conf_by', 'ko_id', 'opening_limit', 'amount', 'closing_limit', 'is_cheque_issued', 'lot_id', 'lot_amount','deposite_account','lot_date',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    // protected $hidden = [
    //     'password', 'remember_token',
    // ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'transaction_date_time' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function csp(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Csp');
    }
 }
```

**this is csp model**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;


class Csp extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $table = 'csps';
    protected $primaryKey = 'ko_id';
    public $incrementing = false;
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = [
        'ko_id', 'ko_name', 'account_number'
    ];
    public function transaction(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Transaction');
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

With Laravel eloquent, it's very simple. You don't need to explicitly write the join commands. You could make use of Laravel's dynamic property.

See [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many).

Code would go as:

```
<?php

$transaction = Transaction::find(20); // assuming 20 is one of the IDs in your database
$csp_details = $transaction->csp;
dd($csp_details); // you would get your csp details here for rows.
```